# RNfirebase phone auth not working with release apk

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have implemented phone based authentication using rnfirebase.

Libraries used:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.3.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^10.3.1",
```

Code Snippet:

SignIn Method to send OTP:

```
newSignIn = async () => {
    let phoneNumber = this.state.phone;
    if (this.validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)) {
      try {
        const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        ToastAndroid.show(JSON.stringify(confirmation), ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        this.setState({ confirm: confirmation });
      } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert("Sorry!", "Error occurred. Check phone number.");
      }
    } else {
      Alert.alert(
        "Sorry!",
        "Invalid Phone Number, make sure to add + country code."
      );
    }
  }
```

When I am testing it on emulator, it is working fine with testing phone numbers. But when I am creating the release apk and installing that apk on my phone then some times it sends OTP and works fine. but some times it is not working, not sending any OTP. I have tried debugging and observed that it is getting into infinite wait on line:

```
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue you need to follow these steps

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click the Gradle Taskbar on the right
3. Double click signingReport from `[your app name] > Tasks > android > signingReport`
4. Take note of the Variant: Release `SHA-1` that is generated. It should be among the first outputted by the task.
5. Append this `SHA-1` to the list of `SHA-1` in your firebase console. You should have 2 now, one for debug and another one for release.
6. Download the fresh `google-services.json` and place it in your `android/app` directory.
7. Rebuild release app.

Comment: Issue is not with these steps, I followed them and on signed apk it is some times working some times not working.

Comment: Just add an ssh key to the Firebase account in the application config. You can use cd android then in an android folder simply run gradlew signingreport if on mac or ./gradlew signing report if on window